# закрытие блока тапом вне его на iphone JS

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari

Есть всплывающий блок на сайте. Я его закрываю кнопкой. Но хочу тапом вне самого блока. Пробовал варианты:

вар1

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    var container = $("inst_nav");
    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0){
        $("inst_nav").removeClass("show_inst");
...
    }
});
```

вар2

```
    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).closest("inst_nav").length) {
        $("inst_nav").removeClass("show_inst");
...     
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

На android устройствах всё работает, как задумано, в любых браузерах. С компа при эмуляции размеров планшетов и пр. так же все закрывается. Но на айфонах в safari и chrome работает криво: закрывает тапом только по картинке вне блока, да ещё и в определнной зоне с 3 тапа.
Как на айфоне реализовать закрытие блока тапом вне него?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('touchstart',function(e) {
if (!$(e.target).closest("inst_nav").length) {
        $("inst_nav").removeClass("show_inst");
        $("#inst_icon").removeClass("close_inst");
        $("header nav ul").removeClass("show_menu");
        $("#menu_icon").removeClass("close_menu");
        }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

в этом варианте всё заработало